# Implement two(2) name spaces under Application in the Manifest file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to implement 2 name spaces under Application in android Manifest file to implement the firebase offline capabilities but it rejects taking 2 name spaces in the manifest file, see: [image: Manifest file]

I tried to extend multiDexApplication in the MiLibrary Class, see:

public class MiLibrary extends Application {

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }

    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    Picasso built = builder.build();
    built.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
    built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);

}
```

but it gives me an error, see the stackTrace: 
[image: stackTrace]

I've also tried searching here on stack-overflow and on Google but there are results or answers related to this, does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: .... What do you want when add 2 name, cannot do this? Because your `MiLibray extend MultiDexApplication`, so only need  name `MiLibray`

Comment: When I extended MultiDexApplication from MiLibrary, I had only One name , which was name =" .MiLibrary" on the Manifest and it gave me the error that I showed from my stackTrace.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: Alright, I'll update it now with real code.

Comment: Can you post your Manifest

Answer (score 1):

First of all in application tag you can define only single attribute for:-

```
android:name=".YourApplication"
```

Secondly, add the following dependency for okHttpClient:-

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```

Your app's gradle file should look like this:-

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14 
    targetSdkVersion //Yours

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}
```

Extend your application with MultiDexApplication class:-

```
public class MiLibrary extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

In your Manifest add name of your application as follows:-

```
<application
android:name=".MiLibrary"
...>
```

Comment: It still doesn't run, it complains about this line from MiLibrary class I posted above: builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));

Comment: please share your app's gradle file.

Comment: I just cleaned the app and it's working fine now, thanks so much buddy.@Karacken